# Is it possible to use lambda in a for loop for this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I want to follow task with lambda function but not sure it's possible.

Let's say I have following list:

```
list =  [3,2,33,45,566,21]
```

The longest length of the list is 566 so `len(566) = 3`.

Then I want to extend the element all element with last digit.

For example, 3 will be 333 and 45 will be 455.

```
Listchange = [333,222,333,455,566,211]
```

Is it possible to achieve this goal with a lambda function?

I guess I have to use lambda and for and if a function in one line.

Another example:

```
list = [1,21,3,4,5344]
```

The maximum length of the list is 4 so extend all list to length 4 with last digit.

```
list = [1111,2111,3333,5344]
```

My trial but first time using lambda:

```
print(list(map(lambda i: for i in range(maxnum)-len(i): i+=i ,x)))
```

Comment: Where is your code that accomplishes anything? [mcve]? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Default-Disclaimer: do not shadow built ins - `list` is already taken by `list()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `str.ljust` method with the `fillchar` parameter set to the last digit of the number:

```
lst = [1, 21, 3, 4, 5344]
list(map(lambda i: int(str(i).ljust(4, str(i % 10))), lst))
```

This returns:

```
[1111, 2111, 3333, 4444, 5344]
```

Comment: is it possible to use for loop inside of lambda?

Comment: If by "for loop" you mean a list comprehension, yes... `(lambda l: [int(str(i).ljust(4, str(i % 10))) for i in l])(lst)`.

Comment: I just have one more question  if I want to save the original value like [1:1111,21:2222,3:3333,4:4444,5344:5344]  what should I do?

Comment: If you mean it as a dict (which is enclosed in curly brackets rather than square brackets), you can use a dict comprehension instead: `(lambda l: {i: int(str(i).ljust(4, str(i % 10))) for i in l})(lst)`

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer as already been provided by @blhsing. However, if anyone is looking for a list comprehension solution, here it is:

```
my_list = [1,21,3,4,5344]
max_length = 4
new_list = [int(x + x[-1]*(max_length-len(x))) for x in map(str, L)]
```

It returns:

```
[1111, 2111, 3333, 4444, 5344]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, based on **blhsing**'s solution which will work for an arbitrary length:

```
inList =  [3,2,33,45,566,21]
inList = list(map(lambda elem: int(str(elem).ljust(len(str(max(inList))),str(elem)[-1])), inList))
print(inList)
```

Output:

```
[333, 222, 333, 455, 566, 211]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of the f-string and the method `format()`:

```
lst = [3, 2, 33, 45, 566, 21]

max_length = max(map(len, map(str, lst)))
list(map(lambda x: int(f'{{:{str(x)[-1]}<{max_length}}}'.format(x)), lst))
# [333, 222, 333, 455, 566, 211]
```